# If $X$ is a bipartite graph with $e$ edges and $λ$ is an eigenvalue show that $ |λ|≤ \sqrt e$

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

If $X$ is a bipartite graph with $e$ edges and $λ$ is an eigenvalue show that $ |λ|≤ \sqrt e$

For bipartite graph of the form $K_{r,s}$ the characteristic polynomial is $λ^{n-2}(λ^2 - rs)=0$
So $λ^2=rs$ which implies $|λ|= \sqrt {rs} ≤ e$
Is this correct?

Comment: Not every bipartite graph is of the form $K_{r,s}$.

Comment: Then how do I solve it?